# Passing a template function as function pointer gives: "insufficient contextual information to determine type"

Tags: python, c++, templates, g++, function-pointers

I am attempting (perhaps foolishly) to create member functions for a Python extension using a template function:

```
template < typename T >
static PyObject* getName( T* self, PyObject* args )
{
   std::string name = self->obj->getName();
   return PyString_FromString( name.c_str() );
}

struct PyMyObject
{
   PyObject_HEAD
   MyObject* obj;
};

static PyMethodDef PyMyObject_methods[] = {
   {"getName", (PyCFunction) getName< PyMyObject >, METH_VARARGS,
      "return this object's name" },
   {NULL}
};
```

Alas, when I did that and tried to compile I received:

```
g++ test.cpp -I /usr/include/python2.4 -lpython2.4
test.cpp:34: error: insufficient contextual information to determine type
```

However if I explicitly assign to a function pointer and then pass the function pointer into the method definition it compiles without error:

```
PyObject* (*PyMyObject_getName)( PyMyObject*, PyObject* ) = getName< PyMyObject >;

static PyMethodDef PyMyObject_methods[] = {
   {"getName", (PyCFunction) PyMyObject_getName, METH_VARARGS,
      "return this object's name" },
   {NULL}
};
```

Why is the explicit declaration of a function pointer necessary? It seems to me that `getName< PyMyObject >` includes all the type information necessary for the compiler to generate the function, so why does the compiler require additional "contextual information"?

Comment: What version of gcc? Possibly just upgrading will solve your problems.

Comment: compiles for me using GCC 4.8.4

Comment: I'm using gcc 4.1.2, apparently compiled circa 2008. Unfortunately my company refuses to keep our tools up to date (hence why I'm using python 2.4), so it will probably require a miracle to persuade someone to upgrade. Sounds like that's the source of the issue though.

Comment: @DanielMcHenry 4.1.2 is ridiculously obsolete.